# A função localStorage não funciona

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Tenho este código:

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "pedro");
```

Só que quando vou ver no *application/Local Storage/File* não está criado *Key* e nem o *Value* e me retorna um erro:

> teste.html:13 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: já chegou a ver primeiro se o navegador é compatível?
[localStorage brower compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Pode ser que seu navegador esteja com a opção: "Bloquear cookies de terceiros e dados do site" ativada. Desative e deverá funcionar normalmente.

Comment: Você precisa compartilhar o navegador que esta usando e também o sistema operacional. Ambos influenciam muito nisso.

Comment: Provavelmente a resposta do @LeonardoTandeli é a correta

Answer (score 1):

Este erro ocorre em navegadores baseados em Chromium, como Chrome, Opera, etc

Conforme é explicado em: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document

Na versão atual do navegador Chrome especificamente, a configuração de COOKIES e outros dados fica no endereço: `chrome://settings/content/cookies`, o erro ocorrerá quando estiver desta forma:

[image: Chrome]

No opera se localiza em `opera://settings/content/cookies`, como na imagem:

[image: Opera]

Estando habilitado irá obter esta exception, então basta desabilitar (o padrão é desabilitado).